# Convergence problem of martingales with bounded increments 1

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, martingales

Let $\{M_n\}$ be a martingale with bounded increments: $|M_n-M_{n-1}|\leq 1$. $M_0=0$. Prove that $\frac{M_n}{n^{\alpha}}$ converges to $0$ a.s. for $\alpha>\frac{1}{2}$.

For this problem, my solution is as follows. I am not sure whether it is correct or not. I first applied Doob's maximal inequality to the non-negative submartingale $\{|M_n|^2\}$ to get some estimate on the deviation:

\begin{align*}
P\{\max_{1\leq i\leq n}{|M_i|}>\epsilon n^\alpha\}&=P\{\max_{1\leq i\leq n}{|M_i|^2}>\epsilon^2 n^{2\alpha}\}\\
&\leq \frac{E[|M_n|^2]}{\epsilon^2 n^{2\alpha}}\\
&=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nE[(M_i-M_{i-1})^2]}{\epsilon^2 n^{2\alpha}}\\
&\leq\frac{1}{\epsilon^2 n^{2\alpha-1}}
\end{align*}

The third equality uses the fact that $L^2$ martingales have orthogonal increments. Second, I took a subsequence $a_n=[n^{\frac{2}{2\alpha-1}}]+1$ and used the above estimate along with Borel-Cantelli lemma to the subsequence $\{M_{a_n}\}$. This gives that for almost every $\omega\in \Omega$, there exists an integer $N(\omega)$ such that

$$
\frac{|M_{a_n}|}{a_n^\alpha}\leq\frac{\max_{1\leq i\leq a_n}{|M_i|}}{a_n^\alpha}\leq\epsilon,\ \ \forall n>N(\omega) 
$$

Particularly, this proves the desired result for the subsequence $\{M_{a_n}\}$. Finally I extended the result to the whole sequence using the sandwiching technique. For each $n$, there exists a unique $k$ such that $a_{k}\leq n<a_{k+1}$. Therefore,

\begin{align*}
\frac{|M_{n}|}{n^\alpha}&\leq \frac{\max_{1\leq i\leq a_{k+1}}{|M_i|}}{a_{k+1}^\alpha}\frac{a_{k+1}^\alpha}{a_{k}^\alpha}\\
&=\frac{\max_{1\leq i\leq a_{k+1}}{|M_i|}}{a_{k+1}^\alpha}(\frac{k+1}{k})^{\frac{2\alpha}{2\alpha-1}}
\end{align*}

The last equality is actually not equality but I write equality for convenience. Tending $n\rightarrow\infty$, then accordingly $k\rightarrow \infty$, the right-hand side goes to $0$. Hence we conclude that $\frac{M_n}{n^{\alpha}}$ converges to $0$ a.s. for $\alpha>\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: An another way to get the required result is to prove the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{M_n-M_{n-1}}{n^\alpha}$ is convergent a.s..

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is good. An alternative way is to use your first estimate on $\Pr\left\{\max_{1\leqslant i\leqslant n}{|M_i|}>\epsilon n^\alpha\right\}$ with $n=2^N$ and conclude with the Borel-Cantelli lemma that the sequence 
$\left(2^{-N\alpha}\max_{1\leqslant i\leqslant 2^N}\left\lvert M_i\right\rvert\right)_{N\geqslant 1}$ converges to zero almost surely. If $2^N\leqslant n\lt 2^{N+1}$, then 
$$
n^{-\alpha}\max_{1\leqslant i\leqslant n}\left\lvert M_i\right\rvert
\leqslant 2^{-N\alpha}\max_{1\leqslant i\leqslant 2^{N+1}}\left\lvert M_i\right\rvert$$
hence the sequence 
$\left(n^{-\alpha}\max_{1\leqslant i\leqslant n}\left\lvert M_i\right\rvert\right)_{N\geqslant 1}$ converges to zero almost surely.

Notice that boundedness of increments is much more than what we need: we would have reached the same conclusion if the quantity $\mathbb E\left[(M_i-M_{i-1})^2\right]$ can be bounded independently of $i$.